# Express REST API > Subject.find query gives me empty array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Get Request on the subject gives me Empty Array when query is Subject.find()
but when i changed it to findOne() it works well, but in my case i need to query all of the subjects associated to user.

I have tried findOne() and it works well but this is not what i want.

```
router.get("/profile", authorization, async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.user;
  try {
    let subject = await Subject.find({ user: id }).populate("user", [
      "schoolId",
      "firstName",
      "lastName"
    ]);

    if (!subject) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "There are no currently enrolled subject to this user"
      });
    }
    res.json(subject);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error! Please Try Again" });
  }
});
```

This should display all of the subject associated to the user.

Comment: are you using same query like `{ user: id }` when you try to use `findOne()`? and also I am not sure about `populate()` syntax that you are using, can you test your `find()` query without using `populate()`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query or syntax here. Please show your subject and user schema, maybe there is some problem with that.

Comment: It is fixed now, Yea there is nothing wrong. i just dont have a collection for subject, But im wondering why the error doesn't shows up.

Comment: i mean the condition where if(!subject)